# Ansible roles task failing docker swarm node join

Tags: docker, ansible, ansible-2.x

I am having problem while joining a worker node with manager node. But i am having issue in the system while join the worker in the cluster.

docker_worker_token set to another host.

```
host1:
    - name: Get the worker join-token.
      shell: docker swarm join-token -q worker
      with_items:
        - "{{ groups['manager'] }}"
      register: docker_worker_token

host2:

    - name: join node to the cluster
      shell: docker swarm join --token {{ hostvars[item]['docker_worker_token'] }} {{ managerip }}:2377
      with_items:
        - "{{ groups['manager'] }}"
```

The error i am getting below like this.

> failed: [188.166.30.64] (item=188.166.17.148) => {"changed": true,
>   "cmd": "docker swarm join --token {'msg': u'All items completed',
>   'changed': True, 'results': [{u'changed': True, u'end': u'2016-09-10
>   13:42:11.439043', '_ansible_no_log': False, u'stdout':
>   u'SWMTKN-1-34rdkhgb6ij6njvzdnutvbt8ee3crelm5as7dm7c7y7s03nvr3-9m0c8vp9hjb84ne90etapxec5',
>   '_ansible_item_result': True, 'item': u'188.166.17.148', u'delta':
>   u'0:00:00.016042', u'cmd': u'docker swarm join-token -q worker',
>   u'stderr': u'', u'rc': 0, 'invocation': {'module_name': u'command',
>   u'module_args': {u'warn': True, u'executable': None, u'_uses_shell':
>   True, u'_raw_params': u'docker swarm join-token -q worker',
>   u'removes': None, u'creates': None, u'chdir': None}}, 'stdout_lines':
>   [u'SWMTKN-1-34rdkhgb6ij6njvzdnutvbt8ee3crelm5as7dm7c7y7s03nvr3-9m0c8vp9hjb84ne90etapxec5'],
>   u'start': u'2016-09-10 13:42:11.423001', u'warnings': []}]}
>   188.166.17.148:2377", "delta": "0:00:00.060083", "end": "2016-09-10 13:42:24.251326", "failed": true, "item": "188.166.17.148", "rc": 1,
>   "start": "2016-09-10 13:42:24.191243", "stderr": "\"docker swarm
>   join\" requires exactly 1 argument(s).\nSee 'docker swarm join
>   --help'.\n\nUsage:  docker swarm join [OPTIONS] HOST:PORT\n\nJoin a swarm as a node and/or manager", "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": [],
>   "warnings": []}

Now how i write the `{{ hostvars[item]['docker_worker_token'] }}` so i can get the token information from the `hostvars`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cmd` value in the output gives you a hint:

```
{{ hostvars[item]['docker_worker_token'].results[0].stdout }}
```

But I almost sure that you use `with_items` for no reason in task *join node to the cluster* and in task, where you set `docker_worker_token` variable? so you end up with unnecessary `results` layer in your variables.

Comment: `docker_worker_token` set to different host. 
- name: Get the worker join-token.
  shell: docker swarm join-token -q worker
  with_items:
    - "{{ groups['manager'] }}"
  register: docker_worker_token